# VS Code snippets for files with specific extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Visual Studio Code allows creating snippets, separated for various language syntaxes. But is it possible to specify not only language, but also extension of a particular file for created snippet?

For example:
I want to create snippet specifically for `c#` `.csproj` file. This file has `xml` syntax, and I could create snippet as an `xml` snippet, but I don't want to see this snippet in other `xml` files except `.csproj`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make snippets show up only with specific file extensions in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932486/how-to-make-snippets-show-up-only-with-specific-file-extensions-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For snippets you use the `scope` parameter:

```
"FrontMatter": {
  "scope": "csharp",         // put your language identifier here
  "prefix": "frontmatter",
  "body": [
      "...",
  ]
},
```

If that scope isn't specific enough, use a keybinding instead which allows for more specificity.

`scope` cannot take content like `editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.csproj/`.

-----------  for keybindings you can use the below  -----------

`"when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.csproj/ && editorLangId == csharp"`

See [when clause operator](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#keyvalue-when-clause-operator)

The `=~` operator allows the use of regular expressions on the right-hand side, so you could do somethinh like

`resourceExtname =~ /\\.(html|css|scss)` to restrict to those three extensions.  It seems odd to me that you do have to specifically add the `.` prior to the extension itself, but it seems you do.

A keybinding which refers to a snippet by `name` - the snippet itself is defined in one of your snippet files follows:

```
{
  "key": "alt+l",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "name": "My groovy comment style"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.csproj/ && editorLangId == csharp"
},
```

or with the actual snippet body right in the keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.csproj/ && editorLangId == csharp",
  "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/([a-z])([A-Z]+(?=[A-Z]))|([A-Z][a-z])/$1 ${2:/downcase}${3:/downcase}/g}"
  }
},
```

Comment: I have the same problem of wanting snippets for specific file extensions, however I am unsure where to put the "when" clause in relation to the snippet. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I tried same but I get a warning as "Property when is not allowed."