# How to make snippets show up only with specific file extensions in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, scope, code-snippets

I've been trying to solve this for weeks but I finally gave up and decided to ask for help..

I wrote a lot of snippets for my web projects (HTML, PHP, JS, VUE, Laravel Blade, etc.) and I created several Global .code-snippet files and they show up in every project or file I open in VSCode, this is not a desired behavior and I'll explain you why.

When I open C++ Projects I don't want the editor to prompt me HTML stuff or Bootstrap icons, I made specific C++ scripts (and added .h extension to the C++ language mode, otherwise they would only work with files with .cpp extension), unfortunately I can't do the same thing with the languages I mentioned before because they're really different languages.

In my `\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets` folder I can see there are two types of files, my custom snippets have .code-snippets extension, language specific snippets have .json extension (example `cpp.json`), syntax is the same.

I could create a copy of `custom.code-snippets` for every file extension and pair it to every language I need (For example `html.json`, `php.json`, `blade.json`, etc.) but this looks really stupid to me because If I want to add a snippet I would have to add it to every file manually.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Add a feature request to add a file global `scope` attribute that applies to all snippets defined in the file unless overruled/defined in the snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution I found is using "scope" for single snippets, but I'm not really satisfied with it:

```
"Bootstrap Icons Alarm Fill": {
    "prefix": ["bsi-alarm","bsi-clock"],
    "body": "<i class='bsi bi-alarm'></i>",
    "description": "Bootstrap Icons Alarm Fill"
},
```

I can add to every snippet: `"scope":"html,php,blade,vue,javascript,xml",` to make it show only with specified file extensions, but I'll have to add it to every snippet (Imagine that only in this file I have more than 1200 snippets, I can easily do it but I'd prefer not to), I'd like to make the entire file specific to several extensions.

Comment: This answer solved it for me, however I suggest you include the `scope` property in the code you show.