# VS code snippets for salesforce

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, salesforce, code-snippets

I am trying to create some vs code snippets for aura and LWC(Salesforce specific languages) so I created one snippet file for javascript now it works in both the languages but is there a way I can restrict JS and html snippets to LWC only or also can someone please confirm how to create snippets for .cmp and .app files to be used on aura HTML, below is my js snippet which works in all sorts of js files and I and trying to restrict it to just lwc

```
  "Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript",
    "prefix": "gss",
    "body": [
        "console.log('$1');",
        "$2"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
```

I tried using when

```
"when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.cmp/"
```

But it says

> Property when is not allowed.

Comment: I expanded on my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907147/836330 so maybe it is more helpful to you.  You are getting that error because `when` clauses only go into keybindings, not snippets.  What is the language mode for your ``cmp` files?  It shows in the lower right-hand corner of the editor.  Usually that is what you want for the scope - lowercased.